# Is Contra-positive and Converse statements just different way of saying a if then statement?

Tags: logic

So i had this question :-

> Write, *If a natural number is odd, then its square is odd* in different ways.

I had included these statements in my answer :-

> $(1): -$ *If the square of a natural number is odd then the number is odd*
>
> $(2) :-$ *If the square of a number is not odd then the number is also not odd*

But to my surprise none these were in the answer key.

Answer key :-

> $(1) :- $ *A natural number is odd implies that its square is odd*
>
> $(2) :- $ *A natural number is odd only if its square is odd*
>
> $(3) :- $ *for a square to be odd it is sufficient that the number is odd*

So my question is,

Are Contra-positive and Converse of a statement, different ways of writing a statement or not ?

I am a bit confuse as they mean the same thing as the original sentence.

Comment: You ***really*** need to provide the answers provided in the key. How are we supposed to be able to tell?

Comment: @probablyme Ok i will edit it.

Comment: The **converse** of a statement is **not** another way of writing the statement. Often a statement is true but its converse is not. In this case, the converse of the given statement happens to be true. But in general if $A$ then $B$ and if $B$ then $A$ are not logically equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contra-positive is an **equivalent** statement to an implication, while the converse is generally not.

For example, take the true statement "if $x=1$ then $x^2=1$". The contrapositive is "If $x^2\neq 1$, then $x\neq 1$", which is a true statement, while the **converse**, "if $x^2=1$ then $x=1$" is false ($-1$ is an $x$ that satisfies the "if" part)!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that but in the question given, it looks to me that they are same. So in the context of this question can we say that those two are just different ways of writing the given statement ?

Comment: Well, **if** it actually turns out that an implication and its converse **are** then yes, you can say that they're "two ways of writing the same statement". In your case, you are right, however you have to prove that the converse is true (you don't get it for free, as it is with the contrapositive).

Comment: Proving that doesn't look very difficult to me as a $odd * odd$ will always give a $odd$.

Answer (score 2):

The converse is only true when you have an "if and only if" statement.  The contrapositve is always true.

Suppose I work every Monday and alternate Tuesdays.

I can make the statement:  "If it is monday I am work today."

The Converse:  "If I am at work, today is a Monday." is not necessarily true.  It could be a Tuesday.

The Contrpositive:  "I am not working today, therefore it is not Monday."  Is true.

In your example $x^2$ is odd $\iff x$ is odd.  The arrow points both ways (if and only if).  The converse is true when the statement is true, and the statement is true when the converse is true.

If you are asked to prove and if and only if statement, you must prove both directions.

Comment: in this context, converse means the same So can we say that it is a different way of writing the original sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

All three statements in the answer key are restatements of the original. They are different ways of writing the same thing.

The original has the form "if X, then Y".

- Answer (1) has the form "X implies Y".
- Answer (2) has the form "X only if Y".
- Answer (3) has the form "X is sufficient for Y".

Note that these answers are neither in converse form nor in contrapositive form.

- Converse of original: "If Y, then X" (not logically equivalent to original)
- Contrapositive of original: "If not Y, then not X" (logically equivalent to original)

Comment: Ok i understand that. So In this specific question why can't we say that Contra-positive and Coverse are just different ways ?

Comment: For sure the contrapositive is logically equivalent to the original, so yes it is a different way of writing the same thing. In your specific question, the converse happens to be *true*. But the converse is not logically equivalent to the original. I assume 'write in different ways' means 'write in logically equivalent ways'.

Comment: You have assumed correctly, but why converse is not logically equivalent to the original ?

Comment: Are you asking in general, or in this specific question?

Comment: Specifically about this question.

Comment: If  "X implies Y" were logically equivalent to "Y implies X" then you could use the exact same proof for both statements. This is not the case for your specific question.

Comment: Let $n$ be a natural number. See if you can use the same chain of reasoning in these two exercises: (1) Assume that $n$ is odd. Prove that $n^2$ is odd. (2) Assume that $n^2$ is odd. Prove that $n$ is odd.

Comment: For (1) i will use the odd number form $2n +1$ and for (2) i will prove the contra-positive of the statement, that is, if $n$ is not odd then $n^2$ is not odd. That made it clear. Just a last question :- if Contra-Positive is logically another way of writing a statemant then does converse $\color{read}{is}$ from a elementary perspective ?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question: "does converse is"??

Comment: Sorry i am really tired, anyway i mean "What converse is ?". In other terms    what is the use of converse ?

Comment: The converse is another statement that may or may not be true, and if true might be an interesting/useful result. You might encounter statements where the converse is true, but to prove the converse requires a totally different line of reasoning. Just be careful not to confuse a statement with its converse -- it's a common error in logic.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, the statement and its converse happen to both be true, but I wouldn't say that they are "the same" or that they "mean the same thing".

The statements "$1+1=2$" and "there are infinitely many prime numbers" are also both true. But are they just two different ways of writing the same statement?

Of course, what is meant by "the same" depends on context, but most of the time one wouldn't want to view these statements as the same. One reason for this is that while they can be proven to be logically equivalent (in the trivial sense that they're both true), such a proof requires you to know what the words involved mean (like natural number and odd number and square), i.e. they require some background non-logical assumptions.

On the other hand, "If a natural number is odd, then it's square is odd" and "A natural number is odd implies that its square is odd" and "If the square of a natural number is not odd, then the natural number is not odd" are all logically equivalent by virtue of their form - you don't need to know the meanings of the non-logical words to see that they are equivalent.

Comment: Ok you made most sense but i have a question, Isn't that just twisting the English words ? i mean i can write 100 more sentences by just using a dictionary.

Comment: Sure - this is not a very interesting exercise, and there's no complete list of correct answers.

Comment: I like this reply.